# Hypothesis on a proportion in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I have a random sample of 100 YES/No answers. 13 of them are "YES". The rest are "NO". 
I have to test a hypotheses on the proportion.

Hypothesis:
H0: p = p0

H1: p > p0

Confidence level is 95%

I have the following code:
(The z.prop function calculates the test statistic.)

```
z.prop = function(k, n, p, p0){ zeta = (p - p0) / (sqrt( p0*(1-p0)/n ) ) 
return(zeta) }

k<- 13
n<- 100
p<- k/n
p0<- 0.1

z <- z.prop(k,n,p,p0)
cat("z: ",z)
z.alpha <- qnorm(0.05,lower.tail=FALSE)
cat("z alpha: ",z.alpha)

pval<- pnorm(abs(z),lower.tail = FALSE)
cat("p-value",pval,"\n")
```

If I use this code then the p-values are different.

```
binom.test(k, n, p = p0,alternative ="greater",conf.level = 0.95)
```

Using my function I got 0.1586553 for the p-value. Using the binom.test function I got p-value = 0.1982.

How is this possible? Is my code wrong, or it is just some kind of rounding error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `z.prop` function implements the same test of the `prop.test` function in `stats` (without the Yates continuity correction):

```
prTest <- prop.test(k, n, p=p0, alternative ="greater", correct = F)
prTest$p.value
# [1] 0.1586553
```

The `binom.test` function implements a different test for proportions: the exact binomial test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When should I use binom.test and prop.test? Is it possible to use the prop.test in my case (100 binary element)? If yes then with or without continuity correction?

Comment: @DàvidNagy You can use prop.test in your case. By default prop.test uses continuity correction. I suggest to use this default and (very important)  to read something about the theory behind the test !